# Why kotlin provide null safety operator but not exception safety operator?

Tags: kotlin, language-lawyer, kotlin-null-safety, exception-safety

If kotlin promotes **safe** code such as:

```kotlin
val currentName = "Some Guy"
getDataFromServer()?.getUsers()?.find { it.name == currentName }?.profilePicture?.let {
  showPicture(it)
} ?: let {
  showAddPictureButton()
}
```

Why there is no similar syntax for exception handling, for example using imaginary `??.` operator:

```kotlin
val someUserId = 123
val newName = "Cool Dude"
connectToDatabase()??.getDao<UserDao>()??.changeUserName(someUserId, newName)??.let { newUserData ->
  reloadView(newUserData)
} ??: let { error ->
  interpretAndHandleError(error)
}
```

I don't see drawbacks here. Is there any reason this is not a part of language?

Comment: Unlike Java, try/catch is an expression in Kotlin. What would this proposed syntax buy us beyond that? It's confusing what happens when something could be null *or* have thrown an exception.

Comment: As for expression, the same applies to `if else`. We could write `if ( someVal != null ) { someVar.property } else { null }` but it's much more healthy to write `someVal?.property`. About nullable return types, yeah, that's a concern. Maybe limit it only to non-null types? Alternatively, `??.` operator still could result in nullable type if expression is of nullable type, and to handle that as well even stronger operator could be used (`???.` operator? That's many question marks though)

Comment: What would `??.` exactly return here? An exception can be more or less any class, and might require custom handling, whereas with null you have a "single" case/value and there's an implicit convetion you don't do anything when you encounter a null.

Comment: @al3c It would still return the same type as original expression. There would have to be separate flow for nullability and error handling. That means that `??.` operator doesn't return `null` on exception, but starts error flow, which can be resolved (or must be resolved) by the `??:` operator.

Comment: It seems you're trying to 'hide' an exception together with a value, which seems quite suprising, you can have variables of any type actually concealing an exception. By the way kotlin has `runCatching` and `Result` which can be used to do something like what you suggest, but in a typesafe way.

Answer (score 4):

It isn't about drawbacks, but about not having sufficient benefits. Consider writing your first example without `?.`:

```
val data = getDataFromServer()
if (data != null) {
    val users = data.getUsers()
    if (users != null) {
        val user = users.find { it.name == currentName }
        if (user != null) ...
    } else null
} else null
```

You can see it's much more complex than the original code. Now consider writing your suggested `??.` without it:

```
try {
    connectToDatabase().getDao<UserDao>().changeUserName(someUserId, newName).let { newUserData ->
        reloadView(newUserData)
    }
} catch(error: Exception) { 
    interpretAndHandleError(error)
}
```

Where is the complexity you want to eliminate?